# Alexa giving me [Object Products] whenever I am trying to get quote of the day

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Alexa is giving me [Object Products] whenever I am trying to get quote of the day using kote-api. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const APP_ID = undefined;
const skill_name = "Quote of the Day";
const kote = require('kote-api');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
   var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
   alexa.appId = APP_ID;
   alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
   alexa.execute();
}; 

var handlers =
{
 'LaunchRequest': function ()
{
  this.emit('QuoteOfDay');
},
'QuoteOfDay': function ()
{
 var quoteDay = kote.goodReads().then(quote => {
 this.emit(quote);
});
 this.emit(':tellWithCard', quoteDay);
  }
};
```

Here is my log output:

```
{
 "version": "1.0",
 "response": {
 "shouldEndSession": true,
 "outputSpeech": {
   "type": "SSML",
  "ssml": "<speak> [object Promise] </speak>"
 }
},
"sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your object to JSON before send it back like below,

```
this.emit(JSON.parse(quote));
```

Comment: did you add JSON.parse in all intents?

Comment: What do you mean by all my intents, the ‘QuoteOfDay’ is my only intent

Comment: All right. I thought you have shared just part of the code. Just to make sure this is the problem of deferred execution can you please emit a hard-coded from 'QuoteOfDay' intent? I mean, this.emit("Hello Quote");